# Are "Orbit Subspaces" Disjoint?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

The orbits of a group action partition the set. Does a linear group action on a vector space break it into a direct sum? I.e. do the subspaces $V_w = \text{span}\left\{g\cdot w: g\in G\right\}$ intersect trivially when not equal? If so, is there is an analogue to the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem; perhaps, $|G| = \dim V_w \cdot |Stab_G(w)|.$

Comment: The formula for $|G|$ is not true, for example if $V$ has dimension one and $G$ acts faithfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group of diagonal $2 \times 2$ matrices acting on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a counterexample to your first question. The span of the orbit of $\langle 1,0 \rangle$ is 1-dimensional, and the span of the orbit of $\langle 1,1 \rangle$ is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.